# Gnome shell theme / decorations broken

Tags: gnome

I've upgraded to 11.04 and replaced unity with gnome shell. Now the controls and window decorations look like if there was "no theme".

I have an ATI HD 3470 and I don't use proprietary drivers (fglrx).

What should I do to get the nice default gnome shell theme?

Screenshot: http://imagebin.org/147358

Comment: have the same problem and /usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-check-accelerated; echo $? returns 0 but i cannot even change themes using gnome-tweak-tool anymore. everything was working fine with gnome 3 and themes some days ago but now it is broken. installing lxappearance does not change anything for me.

Comment: @wywtry: Hi, the answer here helped me. http://superuser.com/questions/268781/ubuntu-gnome-shell-decorations-theme-broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me. I don't know why it happened but "lxappearance" (had to install it using apt-get install lxappearance) run from the terminal fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the info, lxappearance helped - sort of - but probably with gtk2 apps only.